# Prevent Leeching of Paid Content Downloads - But Allow Customers to Re-download

Tags: wordpress, url, download, security, piracy-prevention

I'm planning on selling a bunch of videos online, as part of a paid members area. Customer pays via PayPal and gets access to a members area, where there's links to download the videos. The videos are hosted on a CDN (like Amazon S3 or Rackspace Cloud), which if we just pop the links in, anyone can put up in public and share.

What's the best way to go about making sure only paying customers download the videos and can't share the URLs publicly with others?

I'm using Wordpress & the s2member plugin for the paid members area.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using S3 to host the files, then [Amazon Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/#Does_Amazon_CloudFront_support_access_controls) can let you create one-time [signed URLs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) for paid content.

Comment: To complement this answer, you will also want to associate the PayPal transaction id to your transaction.
It makes customer service *a lot* easier.